# Finding and replacing an unknown

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell to replace a value in a .conf file.
The value being
"LockoutDuration = 30". This works fine using .replace, but I would like to be able to replace it if it said anything, say:
"LockoutDuration = 3231231", and still work. How would I go about finding what's after the "=" sign, and replacing that with my variable? So that it works without knowing what's after it.

Answer (score -2):

Use regular expression in replace:

```
"LockoutDuration = 30" -replace "(\d+)","${1}123453" ## returns: 'LockoutDuration = 123453'
```